# strptime outputing NA when I try and convert from "%Y-%m" format

Tags: r

Strptime outputs NA when I set format to "%Y-%m"

I have tried adding the day as a test and it worked, but whenever I do "%Y-%m" or "%m" i get NA

> print(strptime("2007-07", format = "%Y-%m"))
>   [1] NA
>
> print(strptime("07", format = "%m"))
>   [1] NA
>
> print(strptime("2007", format = "%Y"))
>   [1] "2007-07-30 EDT"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use library `zoo`. It is useful when you have to deal with dates like that.

```
require(zoo)
yearmon(c(2017,01))
```

Then you can manipulate the object `yearmon`.

```
as.Date(yearmon(c(2017,01)))

[1] "2017-01-01" "7-01-01"
```